# Pass ID value to SharePoint Dialog using query string and javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, query-string

If I use the following:

```
function openFSCUploadDialog()
{
    var diaOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    diaOptions.url = "<server>/mySite/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={E2489E65-BE6T-4569-BE36-FCE8D47DG8EB}&IsDlg=1&ReqID=1";
    diaOptions.width = 700;
    diaOptions.height = 310;
    diaOptions.title = "Trying to Pass the Value in the Dialog URL";
    diaOptions.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallBack);
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(diaOptions);
}
```

to open a dialog of the upload.aspx for the site collection. I am trying to use javascript/jquery and read the value from a query string that I have passed in the above dialog.url. I am unsure of how to access the value in the code behind of the upload.aspx using javascript / jquery.

I would really appreciate any context / help on this.

EDIT: yes sorry I would like to access the value in the something like the `$(document).ready` of the form.

Comment: do you want to access the query string value in the code behind using javascript???

Comment: yes if that is possible, that is exactly what I am trying to get at. that is if i am not wrong on the terminology? kinda new at this. I am looking to pass the value in the above manner, and access via doc ready of the upload.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12197444/413670

Comment: thanks...that is my answer. wasn't sure if I could use such an approach with SharePoint Dialog since the qryString was just within the dialog options, but it appears to work. You answered! thanks

Comment: /_layouts.aspx is a SharePoint page. You shouldn't be touching it. Rather make a copy of the page and then add the solution code to that. By the way there's a really neat JQuery passer on github [https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser)